# HTML popup window with equation

Tags: javascript, html, css, popup

I am learning HTML, CSS and Javascript, I started 3 days ago so don't expect an expert here. I have the following MWE:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>References with popup windows</title>
    
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <!-- Support for math --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML"></script> 
    <script type="text/x-mathjax-config">                                                                                         
        MathJax.Hub.Config({                                                                                                      
            tex2jax: {                                                                                                            
              inlineMath: [ ['$','$'], ["\\(","\\)"] ],                                                                           
              processEscapes: true                                                                                                
            }                                                                                                                     
        });                                                                                                                       
    </script>
    <!----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------->
    <style>
    .equation {
        display: table;
        width: 100%;
    }
    .equation__content, .equation__number {
        display: table-cell;
    }
    .equation__content {
        width: 90%;
    }
    .equation__number {
        text-align: right;
        font-family: serif;
    }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="equation">
        <equation id="my first equation" class="equation__content">
            $$f(x) = 5x^2$$
        </equation>
        <div class="equation__number">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;(1)</div>
    </div>
    <p>See equation <a class="cross-reference-link" href="#my first equation" onmouseover="popup(my_first_equation)">(1)</a>.</p>
    
</body>

</html>
```

and as you can see in the text inside the `<p>` tag I created a clickable reference to the equation which is fine. Now I would like that the referenced equation is displayed in a small box when the mouse hovers over the reference, something like this:

[image]

I have been reading many tutorials and instructions on how to do similar things, but all of them only show a simple popup text. Here I want to display a "more complicated object" that is already rendered in the page. I think this is similar to what Wikipedia has for the references.

How can I do this?

Comment: Just use the same logic as the normal text tooltip but instead of the text, copy the equation related code there. That should suffice.

Comment: Yes, I have something that is partially working. However I have to copy the equation again. Isn't it possible to somehow tell the popup window to show whatever is in some `id` somewhere else? This I really don't know how to do it.

Comment: Even wikipedia adds the tooltip later using javascript to the dom so i don't think there's a way to tell the popup winow to show some other element. Cause the popup window in the end, is HTML code just styled using CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I managed to solve this problem following [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15458021/css-javascript-mouseover-popup-box) and [this tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_tooltip.asp). Here is my code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>References with popup windows</title>
    
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <!-- Support for math --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML"></script> 
    <script type="text/x-mathjax-config">                                                                                         
        MathJax.Hub.Config({                                                                                                      
            tex2jax: {                                                                                                            
              inlineMath: [ ['$','$'], ["\\(","\\)"] ],                                                                           
              processEscapes: true                                                                                                
            }                                                                                                                     
        });                                                                                                                       
    </script>
    <!----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------->
    <style>
    .equation {
        display: table;
        width: 100%;
    }
    .equation__content, .equation__number {
        display: table-cell;
    }
    .equation__content {
        width: 90%;
    }
    .equation__number {
        text-align: right;
        font-family: serif;
    }
    </style>
    <style>
        .popup_cross_reference {position:relative; }
        .popup_cross_reference span {display: none;}
        .popup_cross_reference_hover {position:relative;}
        .popup_cross_reference_hover span {
            display: block;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: White;
    z-index:1000;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    margin-right: 5px;
    margin-left: 5px;
    background-color: #444;
    color: #fff;
    border-radius: 10px;
        }
    </style>

</head>

<body>
    <div class="equation">
        <equation id="my first equation" class="equation__content">
            $$\intop_0^1f(x)dx=\pi + \sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{1}{x^k}$$
        </equation>
        <div class="equation__number">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;(1)</div>
    </div>
    <p>See 
        <span class="popup_cross_reference" onMouseOver="javascript:this.className='popup_cross_reference_hover'" onMouseOut="javascript:this.className='popup_cross_reference'">
            <a class="cross-reference-link" href="#my first equation">(1)</a>
            <span>
                $\intop_0^1f(x)dx=\pi + \sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{1}{x^k}$
            </span>
        </span>. This is doing exactly what I wanted to do. I would have prefered not to have to copy the equation, but whatever... I took this solution from <a href="https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15458021/css-javascript-mouseover-popup-box">here</a>.
    </p>
    
</body>

</html>
```

I don't know why it does not work fine here on SO but outside it works beautifully.

Answer (score 1):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>References with popup windows</title>
    
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <!-- Support for math --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML"></script> 
    <script type="text/x-mathjax-config">                                                                                         
        MathJax.Hub.Config({                                                                                                      
            tex2jax: {                                                                                                            
              inlineMath: [ ['$','$'], ["\\(","\\)"] ],                                                                           
              processEscapes: true                                                                                                
            }                                                                                                                     
        });                                                                                                                       
    </script>
    <!----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------->
    <style>
    .equation {
        display: table;
        width: 100%;
    }
    .equation__content, .equation__number {
        display: table-cell;
    }
    .equation__content {
        width: 90%;
    }
    .equation__number {
        text-align: right;
        font-family: serif;
    }
    .tip {
        position: relative;
        display: inline-block;
        border-bottom: 1px dotted black;
    }

    .tip .pop {
        visibility: hidden;
        width: 120px;
        background-color: white;
        color: black;
        text-align: center;
        border-style: solid;
        border-color: black;
        border-radius: 10px;
        padding: 5px 0;

        position: absolute;
        z-index: 1;
     }

    .tip:hover .pop {

        visibility: visible;
     }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="equation">
        <equation id="my first equation" class="equation__content">
            $$f(x) = 5x^2$$
        </equation>
        <div class="equation__number">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;(1)</div>
  </div>
    <p>See equation<div class="tip">(1)
      <span class="pop">
        <equation id="my first equation" 
        class="equation__content">
          $$f(x) = 5x^2$$
        </equation>
      </span>
    .</p>
   </div>
    
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I think this can help you tho, I am earning reputation, don't forget to tip me tho